# How to remove unused values from ggplot2 scale_color_manual()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think it is a recent change in ggplot2 that all the values defined in the scale_manual function are included in the legend, but I want only the values that are in the data set in the legend.

Below is a minimal example, in which "C" is filtered from the data set but still appears in the legend. Is there an easy fix to remove "C" from the legend?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df_dummy <- tribble(
    ~label, ~x, ~y,
    "A",     1,  1,
    "B",     2,  2,
    "C",     3,  3,
    "D",     4,  4
)

myColors <- viridis::viridis_pal(option = "H")(4)
names(myColors) <- factor(df_dummy$label)
dummy_col_scale <- scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = myColors)

df_dummy %>% 
    filter(label != "C") %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x, y, color = label)) +
    geom_point() +
    dummy_col_scale
```

```
sessionInfo()

R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.0.5   ggplot2_3.3.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13   magrittr_2.0.1   
 [3] tidyselect_1.1.1  munsell_0.5.0    
 [5] cowplot_1.1.1     viridisLite_0.4.0
 [7] colorspace_2.0-2  R6_2.5.1         
 [9] rlang_0.4.10      fansi_0.4.2      
[11] tools_4.0.3       grid_4.0.3       
[13] gtable_0.3.0      utf8_1.2.1       
[15] cli_3.0.1         DBI_1.1.1        
[17] withr_2.4.2       ellipsis_0.3.2   
[19] digest_0.6.27     assertthat_0.2.1 
[21] tibble_3.1.1      lifecycle_1.0.1  
[23] crayon_1.4.1      gridExtra_2.3    
[25] farver_2.1.0      purrr_0.3.4      
[27] viridis_0.6.0     vctrs_0.3.8      
[29] glue_1.4.2        labeling_0.4.2   
[31] compiler_4.0.3    pillar_1.6.4     
[33] generics_0.1.0    scales_1.1.1     
[35] pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: You are right. This is an issue introduced with the latest version of ggplot2. As a workaround you could add `limits=force`.  See https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4511#issuecomment-866185530. That issue will probably be fixed with next update (and should already be available in the devel version). See https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/4619

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to set `limits = force` in `scale_color_manual`.

```
df_dummy <- structure(list(label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), x = c(1, 2, 3, 
4), y = c(1, 2, 3, 4)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L))

myColors <- viridis::viridis_pal(option = "H")(4)
names(myColors) <- factor(df_dummy$label)

dummy_col_scale <-
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend",
                     values = myColors,
                     limits = force)

df_dummy %>%
  filter(label != "C") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = label)) +
  geom_point() +
  dummy_col_scale
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Great, many thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You may just simply remove `C` from `myColors` which is named vector, similar work with `filter(label != "C")`.

```
myColors
          A           B           C           D 
"#30123BFF" "#1AE4B6FF" "#FABA39FF" "#7A0403FF" 

myColors[names(myColors) != "C"]
          A           B           D 
"#30123BFF" "#1AE4B6FF" "#7A0403FF"
```

Then, try

```
df_dummy %>% 
  filter(label != "C") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = label)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = myColors[names(myColors) != "C"])
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is the 'cleanest' solution (+1), but without more details it's difficult to know what option will suit OP best.

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thanks for suggestion. I add some details and code but I'm not sure if it's enough. Thanks again :D.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are a few solutions to your problem. One potential solution is to do the filtering first then select 3 colours:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df_dummy <- tribble(
  ~label, ~x, ~y,
  "A",     1,  1,
  "B",     2,  2,
  "C",     3,  3,
  "D",     4,  4
)

df2 <- df_dummy %>% 
  filter(label != "C")

myColors <- viridis::viridis_pal(option = "H")(3)
names(myColors) <- factor(df2$label)
dummy_col_scale <- scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = myColors)

df2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = label)) +
  geom_point() +
  dummy_col_scale
```

[image]

Another option is to set limits in dummy_col_scale, i.e.

```r
df_dummy <- tribble(
  ~label, ~x, ~y,
  "A",     1,  1,
  "B",     2,  2,
  "C",     3,  3,
  "D",     4,  4
)

df2 <- df_dummy %>% 
  filter(label != "C")

myColors <- viridis::viridis_pal(option = "H")(4)
names(myColors) <- factor(df2$label)
dummy_col_scale <- scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = myColors,
                                      limits = c("A", "B", "D"))

df2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = label)) +
  geom_point() +
  dummy_col_scale
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>